# Insert text before each line of the selected text in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have some text where I can add my text before and after selection :

```
Hello, I can insert text before and after this by javascript.

1. How to insert text

2. before each line

a. if text is separeted by /g
```

For surround selection I'm using this code:

```
function surroundSelection(textBefore, textAfter, color) {

    if (window.getSelection) {
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    var selectedText = sel.toString();
    if(selectedText.trim() != "") {

            if (sel.rangeCount > 0) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0);
            var startNode = range.startContainer, startOffset = range.startOffset;

            var startTextNode   = document.createElement(\'span\');
            startTextNode.style.backgroundColor = color;
            var startTextNode_t = document.createTextNode(textBefore);
            startTextNode.appendChild(startTextNode_t);

            var endTextNode   = document.createElement(\'span\');
            endTextNode.style.backgroundColor = color;
            var endTextNode_t = document.createTextNode(textAfter);
            endTextNode.appendChild(endTextNode_t);

            var boundaryRange = range.cloneRange();
            boundaryRange.collapse(false);
            boundaryRange.insertNode(endTextNode);
            boundaryRange.setStart(startNode, startOffset);
            boundaryRange.collapse(true);
            boundaryRange.insertNode(startTextNode);

            range.setStartAfter(startTextNode);
            range.setEndBefore(endTextNode);

            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);

            }
        }

    }
    }
```

The result after selecting text can be :

```
**!!its_my_text_start!!**Hello, I can insert text before and after this by javascript.

1. How to insert text

2. before each line **!!its_my_text_end!!**

a. if text is separeted by /g
```

But now I need to select text of the list, and put my text at the beginning and at the end of each element, which separeted by /g.

For example:

```
Hello, I can insert text before and after this by javascript.

**El_1_start** 1. How to insert text **El_1_end**

**El_2_start** 2. before each line **El_2_end**

**El_3_start** a. if text is separeted by /g **El_3_end**
```

How can I do this by using window.getSelection?

Comment: I assume this is textarea?

Comment: No, text is selected by mouse on html page with a lot of different tags(<p>, <div>, <h1>). After using var sel = window.getSelection(); var selectedText = sel.toString(); I get only text without tags and work with it